# AWS Elemental MediaConvert MPEG-DASH: Can't create mpd with manifest profile:"urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-on-demand:2011"

Tags: amazon-web-services, mpeg-dash, aws-elemental, aws-media-convert

I'm using AWS Elemental MediaConvert to transcode video files into MPEG-DASH (with DRM encryption).

The `mpd` files generated are having manifest profile `urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-main:2011`. I have tried this with different system presets available for the video , but always ended up with same manifest profile. Some settings I used are:

Output group: `DASH ISO` with `Segment control: SEGMENTED_FILES`
  Output 1: `Video Codec: MPEG-4 AVC (H.264)`,
plus different combinations of all available settings.

Is there any thing I'm missing or any specific combination of these settings that can create an `mpd` with following profiles?

The media player we use supports only `urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-on-demand:2011` and `urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-live:2011` profiles.

Unfortunately, we cannot change the media player as it is shipped with the SDK from DRM provider.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you let us know all the settings parameters ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the DASH-ISO output group options set `HbbTV Compliance` as `HBBTV 1.5`. This should give you `isoff-live` manifest profile.

Please refer the attached [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlS89.png).

Comment: But the manifest profile is now `urn:hbbtv:dash:profile:isoff-live:2012,urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-live:2011`, not `urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-live:2011` or `urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-on-demand:2011`.

Comment: Anyway, this works with my SDK player. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mediaconvert/latest/apireference/mediaconvert-api.pdf) of AWS Elemental MediaConvert,

H264CodecProfile is allowed following types

BASELINE
HIGH
HIGH_10BIT
HIGH_422
HIGH_422_10BIT
MAIN

Is it possible to change the codec level to BASELINE and try?

When you say player doesn't support mpeg-dash profile `urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-main:2011` is it about the mpeg-dash profile or actually decoder doesn't support `H264 main` profile?

Comment: The player can play `.mpd` files with `urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-on-demand:2011` profile. However, with the isoff-main profile, it is not working.

Comment: I've tried with BASELINE, but with no success. Resulted MPD looks like:```<MPD xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011" xmlns:cenc="urn:mpeg:cenc:2013" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011 http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/MPEG-DASH_schema_files/DASH-MPD.xsd" type="static" minBufferTime="PT60S" profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-main:2011" mediaPresentationDuration="PT5.300S">```